# Redirect from folder to root

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like to move all content from `/downloads/assets/` folder to `/downloads/` folder.

How do I add redirect for `/downloads/assets/{anystring}` to  `/downloads/{anystring}`?

Now I manually add every redirect like this:

```
RewriteRule ^downloads/assets/views?$ /downloads/views [L]
```

But it's a dream job. Can we use variables instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spend some time with [the `RewriteRule` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule), as this is a very rudimentary usage.  You will need to capture everything after `assets/` in `(.*)` and rewrite it as `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^downloads/assets/(.*) downloads/$1 [L]
```

The above will perform a silent internal rewrite. If you need to redirect the browser rather than silently rewrite, use `[L,R=301]` instead of `[L]`.